# TypeError: jsonServer.create is not a function when trying to deploy on Heroku

Tags: node.js

[Image of the code issue, says jsonServer.create is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crAQF.png)

Comment: Please provide your source code as text here and also, write down the error.

Answer (score 2):

You must be using an earlier version of json-server. Run npm i json-server@latest

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just change path to db file:

```js
const router = jsonServer.router('db.json')
```